# не могу установить линукс в виртуалбокс, выдает ошибку Generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1

Tags: linux, ubuntu

ошибка установки линукс

```
Generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
```

Comment: непонятно, что где и как вы делаете, и откуда именно получаете такую ошибку.

Comment: Разобрался сам просто добавив памяти в виртуальную машину

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в другом форуме нашел :

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/libpaper1*
sudo dpkg --configure -D 777 libpaper1
sudo apt -f install
```